# Loading a TMX file with Java

Tags: java, tilemap, loading

I use the program Tiled to create tile maps, which export to the TMX format. However, I can't find a way to load them into my LWJGL game. I don't want anything that renders them automatically, I want to render them myself. I just need a way to read the data required for me to know where and what to draw in my game. Are there any libraries or code I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: you can take a look http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/support-for-tmx-maps/ in the java section and simply look at how they did it.

Also if you zip the tmx it's using base64, if you know how that works you can decompress the data yourself otherwise use the plane xml structure and load an xml as you normally would.